# Directory-local variables error: wrong-type-argument stringp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have the following .dir-locals.el:

```
((c++-mode . ((irony-compile-flags-work-dir . "/home/aparulekar/Developer/GamePlay")
              (irony-compile-flags . (list "-Igameplay/src"
                                       "-Iexternal-deps/bullet/include"
                                       "-Iexternal-deps/oggvorbis/include"
                                       "-Iexternal-deps/libpng/include"
                                       "-Iexternal-deps/zlib/include"
                                       "-Iexternal-deps/lua/include"
                                       "-Iexternal-deps/glew/include")))))
```

When I visit any file in that folder, I get the following error:

```
Directory-local variables error: (wrong-type-argument stringp irony-compile-flags)
```

Could someone please tell me why I can't assign a list to a directory-local variable?

(This is for https://github.com/sarcasm/irony-mode)

*Edit* - [Anton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15001572/288634), plus I had some dir-local unsafe-variable-related suppression going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`irony-compile-flags` is defined as a list of strings (`repeat string`) in its `defcustom` form.

In your `.dir-locals.el`, you've forgotten that you're providing *values*, not *lisp expressions* to be evaluated. Hence the `list` symbol is redundant, and that's what breaks the type check: you're setting `irony-compile-flags` to a list starting with symbol `list`. Try this:

```
((c++-mode . ((irony-compile-flags-work-dir . "/home/aparulekar/Developer/GamePlay")
              (irony-compile-flags .  ("-Igameplay/src"
                                       "-Iexternal-deps/bullet/include"
                                       "-Iexternal-deps/oggvorbis/include"
                                       "-Iexternal-deps/libpng/include"
                                       "-Iexternal-deps/zlib/include"
                                       "-Iexternal-deps/lua/include"
                                       "-Iexternal-deps/glew/include")))))
```